# PYQT5 Lineedit settext() not refreshing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am currently working on a small python project with PyQT5, but I am having difficulty refreshing the text I have set, I have to click on the lineedit box to see it. But it is set, so if I used the .text() method, I get what I set it to, but I don't see it unless I click on the box, here is an example and code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJuFA4NlKmM&feature=youtu.be

```
def isbnlookup(self):
        isbn = self.lineEdit.text()
        try:
            bookisbn = isbnlib.meta(str(isbn))
            # title = bookisbn['Title']
            if len(bookisbn) > 0:
                title = bookisbn['Title']
                authors = bookisbn['Authors']
                authors = " ".join(authors)

                self.lineEdit_2.setText(title)
                self.lineEdit_4.setText(authors)
                #self.object.addbook(title, authors,isbn)
```

Comment: Probably related to [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68521) about widgets not redrawn on MacOS. Try calling `repaint()` for each line edit after setting their text.

Comment: what is your OS? and provide a [mre]

Comment: @musicamante Thank you so much, repaint fixed it